# Manually adding e-commerce transactions in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

we've had some problems with the tracking of the transactions in Google Analytics in our e-commerce website, and now we've lost a couple of months of data due to a configuration error.

Is it possible to bulk import in some way these transactions, along with their additional parameters (date of event, transaction code, money amount)?

We know when every one of these events has taken place, but we would like to import it back into Analytics to have the complete statistics.

Thank you for the help

Answer (score 1):

If the data is in MySQL say for example.

1. Run a MySQL command which pulls all the orders from the `date_you_want_start_from` and then limit it till the `date_you_want_to_end_from`
2. With this data, then create a MySQL view call it `"import_table"`
3. Create a PHP and XML script which loads all the data from `import_table`, it then writes and fills the XML feed
4. Just run that XML feed now inside your analytic loop JavaScript and it will loop and basically add data into the past for you.

Note: PHP, XML and MySQL is just a scenario to give you a head on to do it.

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem as user1764982. I have my table with the missing transactions - how to add the date of the event? Will GA take it into account? I thought you can only add data for the current date and not modify historical data which is already processed.

Comment: This is missing the point so much. How does it "add data into the past for you" when you haven't given it the date of the transaction?