# Add past ecommerce data to Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics

My question is: How do I add previous sale data to Google Analytics so that GA will display the information on the correct dates? (I could just add them all right now, but then GA will show 50 some-odd orders for this date/time).

I found this: [Manually adding e-commerce transactions in Google Analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13009192/manually-adding-e-commerce-transactions-in-google-analytics) but that answer is missing some key information.

E-commerce tracking had not been running for several months, so I want to add that data into Google Analytics.

I have no issue pulling the necessary order information, but (as a user asked in the comments) how do I tell Google Analytics what date those orders are from?

Comment: You can't. If you send this data to Google Analytics it will understand it all happened at the time your script ran.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you technically can't do such thing, unfortunately. If you look at available [parameters for Analytics requests](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters), you **can't set date/time manually**.

Comment: Harumph. This seems like an oversight. Oh well, thanks anyway

Comment: @petr Great!! was searching for this and it saved my time... Is there any official doc by Google, that this cant be done?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the [qt parameter](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#qt). However, they don't guarantee that with more then 4 hours item will be included.

Comment: Thanks for that - I'm guessing that won't work for "old" data, as you described